# How to attach labels to dataset in PyTorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am attempting to create machine learning models (GNB and decision tree models) using pytorch + tensorflow. The dataset is split into images as png files and there is a csv file with labels for each image. Each image is referenced in the csv file as e.g., img0001.png. I need the labels to be with the images rather than separate so that I can use the in the model. What is the best way to go about this?

'''
labels = np.array(labels)
labels = labels.reshape(1, -1)

model = GaussianNB()
model.fit(IMG_DIR, labels)
'''

error:    1203         "y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape {} instead.".format(shape)
1204     )

ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (1, 656) instead.

Answer (score 2):

not sure exactly what you want to achieve but it seems like you want something like a dataset class in Torch. I will a link for a work I did before, hope it will work for you:

https://github.com/Khaliladib11/INM705-CW-Khalil-Aziz/blob/main/Semnatic%20Segmentation/CityScapes.py

Comment: I was able to use the solution above and it worked, but I still am encountering an error when trying to call the model. I will add the code and the error into the original post above. It is an error dealing with the list of labels being a 1d array.

Answer (score 0):

You usually do have those things separately, however they should be in the same order. Let `X` be the images and `y` be the labels, then you can do this:

```
# allows to concatenate path fragments
from os.path import join
# allows to search for all files of a type
from glob import glob
# allows you to handle csv files
import pandas as pd

IMG_DIR = "my/img/dir/"

# your sorted img files
img_paths = list(sorted(glob(join(IMG_DIR, "*.png")))

def read_img(path):
  # your image load method of choice
  img = ...
  return img

# all loaded imgs
imgs = [read_img(p) for p in img_paths]

# labels
df = pd.read_csv("my.csv", sep=",")
labels = list(sorted(df.sort_values(by="identifier that is the same as the image name")["mylabelcolumn"].tolist()))

# this does not work if there is no 1:1 mapping from imgs to labels
len(labels) == len(img_paths)

# here, label[123] corresponds to img_paths[123] / imgs[123]
```

Note: There are many ways to load image data (OpenCV, tensorflow, pytorch, PIL, ...).

Note: this loads all imgs to memory... this won't work for big datasets.

Comment: I tried the method above, but once I try to toss it into a model it still gives me an error I have encountered after trying many different approaches. I will add the error into the og post, it has to deal with the list of labels being a 1d array and I have tried the reshape (both 1,-1 & -1,1) but cannot get it to work. Thanks for the help, your solution worked.